# OpenGL being stubborn, not allowing texture mapping

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm working on a game engine, that uses BMP texture files on MD3 model files. Unfortunately for me, it isn't working at all. I've tried everything, to no avail. Since I wrote the loaders myself, I looked at them, and fixed a few bugs in them, but still, I just get a gray lighted model.

Here's my rendering code:

```
void drawmd3(md3& model, GLuint tex)
{
    int i = 0;
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-1.5,0,-24);
    glRotatef(270,0,0,1);
    glRotatef(-90,0,1,0);
    glRotatef(a,0,0,1);
    while(i<model.surfnum)
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
        int j = 0;
        while(j<model.surfs.at(i).trinum)
        {
                int tmp = model.surfs.at(i).tris.at(j).indexes[0];
                int tmp1 = model.surfs.at(i).tris.at(j).indexes[1];
                int tmp2 = model.surfs.at(i).tris.at(j).indexes[2];

            float norms[3];
            norms[0] = convert_normals0(model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp).normal);
            norms[1] = convert_normals1(model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp).normal);
            norms[2] = convert_normals2(model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp).normal);
            float norms1[3];
            norms1[0] = convert_normals0(model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp1).normal);
            norms1[1] = convert_normals1(model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp1).normal);
            norms1[2] = convert_normals2(model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp1).normal);
            float norms2[3];
            norms2[0] = convert_normals0(model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp2).normal);
            norms2[1] = convert_normals1(model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp2).normal);
            norms2[2] = convert_normals2(model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp2).normal);

            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

            glNormal3f(norms[0],norms[1],norms[2]);
            glTexCoord2f(model.surfs.at(i).st.at(tmp).st[0],1-model.surfs.at(i).st.at(tmp).st[1]);
            glVertex3f(model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp).coord[0]/64, model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp).coord[1]/64, model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp).coord[2]/64);
            glNormal3f(norms1[0],norms1[1],norms1[2]);
            glTexCoord2f(model.surfs.at(i).st.at(tmp1).st[0],1-model.surfs.at(i).st.at(tmp1).st[1]);
            glVertex3f(model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp1).coord[0]/64, model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp1).coord[1]/64, model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp1).coord[2]/64);
            glNormal3f(norms2[0],norms2[1],norms2[2]);
            glTexCoord2f(model.surfs.at(i).st.at(tmp2).st[0],1-model.surfs.at(i).st.at(tmp2).st[1]);
            glVertex3f(model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp2).coord[0]/64, model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp2).coord[1]/64, model.surfs.at(i).verts.at(tmp2).coord[2]/64);

            glEnd();
            j++;
        }
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Here's my init code:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glGenTextures(1,&tex[0]);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[0]);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, img.img.imgwidth, img.img.imgheight, 0, GL_RGBA8, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.data);
```

Comment: Does it make any difference if you do another glEnable just before you bind?

Comment: +1 Just for the title - Of course software can't be stubborn, but when OpenGL isn't doing what you want there's always a million things it could be!

Comment: I like the `glBegin()` per triangle.  That will totally not be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: By the way, if you really need to use `glBegin/glEnd`, then be sure not to use `std::vector::at` in such performance-critical code, as the range-checks are just not worth it. But maybe it is some other class you're using. And of course genpfault is rigth about the silly per-triangle `glBegin/glEnd`, but I guess that's not the only performance problem here, considering those `convert_` functions and the `glBegin/glEnd` in general.

Comment: If you bind a small solid-color texture, do you see that color?

Answer (score 3):

That's your problem right there:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
             0, 
             GL_RGBA8, 
             img.img.imgwidth, 
             img.img.imgheight, 
             0, 
             GL_RGBA8,    <<<<<<<<<<----------
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
             img.data);
```

The token you're using for the *format* parameter is not allowed. From the reference:

> *format*
>
> Specifies the format of the pixel data. The following symbolic values are accepted: GL_COLOR_INDEX, GL_RED, GL_GREEN, GL_BLUE, GL_ALPHA, GL_RGB, GL_BGR, GL_RGBA, GL_BGRA, GL_LUMINANCE, and GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA.

Thus no texture will be loaded and you end up with the default white of a not setup texture.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I used GL_RGBA for that parameter. EDIT: OK, it sorta works now, but the image flashes onscreen for a split-second, and disappears, so I can't really tell.

Comment: It's not working correctly, it turns out that for some textures, it does something, but not for others. I now made made everything just RGB.

Comment: @DariusGoad: It works only for certain textures? Are those textures that work of power-of-2 sizes, e.g. 128x64, or 512x512? Could you please tell us, which OpenGL version you do have? `glGetString(GL_VERSION);`.

Comment: They are powers of 2(The tested texture is 512*512), and I have a REALLY old computer, so I have a REALLY old OpenGL: 2.1.2

Comment: OK, it FINALLY WORKS, but the texture's a little screwed up.

Comment: @DariusGoad: Screwed up, like skewed and funny colors, fuzzy edges? Then you've probably got an alignment problem. Please read the manual about the pixel store parameters: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glPixelStore.xml